# Will InstanceContextMode.PerCall in WCF instantiate all static variables/methods?

Tags: c#, wcf, static

In my WCF code, user's id and name are stored in static variables. It is retrieved from HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name and a database hit. Also there are other static variables to store connection string, log file related stuff etc.

Recently i found myself in a race condition where a second call from my client set the user name when the first call was still processing. This resulted in first call reading user data updated by the second call.

To avoid this, I read about InstanceContextMode.PerCall and how it makes static variables behave like non-static for every call.

My questions are

1) If i use InstanceContextMode.PerCall, does that mean it will instantiate all static variables and methods? I am planning to use this only to get new user data for every call. However, I assume this will also make a new instance  for connection string static variable, log file and other static variables. Is this correct? Will it affect performance (reading again from web.config etc)?

2) Is there a way to use InstanceContextMode.PerCall but to create instance only for user data related static variables and leave the connection string related static variables?

3) Is a dispose method ( implementing IDispose) mandatory to dispose off the static variables once the call is done?

Comment: Regular static variables are initialized once per AppDomain and are shared between all threads. That means you cannot store per-user information in static variables (as you already found out) and InstanceContextMode.PerCall does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

First of all not sure why you have all those data in a static variable? that looks like a bad design. When you say `InstanceContextMode.PerCall`; to my understanding every call have a separate copy of the data and it's unique per call.

If you want your data to be not modified then try declaring them as `static readonly` instead. Lastly, you should opt for a better design rather.

Comment: This is an existing code. I did not design. The code gets user info from HttpContext during session_start in global.asax. Sometimes it reads user info from wcf request's header (custom code). They are in different csproj.  What do you suggest to get rid of static variable? Passing it as parameters down the line is lot of code change. That's why i wanted to go with InstanceContextMode.PerCall